# How to specify an app's name while running a Heroku command?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, heroku

I've just run `heroku run rails db:migrate` to add some new columns to my production tables after `git push heroku master` but I receive the error

> Simons-MBP:gourmet_coffee Simon$ heroku run rake db:migrate
>
> ▸    Error: Could not find git remote stagegcl in  /Users/Simon/gourmet_coffee
>
> ▸    remotes: heroku staging

So it's clearly trying to run on my staging app.  How do I change this so it's my production app?

Answer (score 1):

If you have multiple apps for the same project, you can use `--app` or `-a` flag to specify the name of the app.

```
heroku run rails db:migrate --app <the-name-of-your-app>
```